# REACTIVE FORM SPECIFIC VALIDATION no message

Tags: angular

I want to display error message "name must have at least 3 characters" the red bar appears but no message.

**signup-form.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">username</label>
            <input formControlName="username"
             class="form-control" 
            id="username"
            type="text">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="username.touched && username.invalid">
                    <div *ngIf="username.errors.required">username is required !</div>
                    <div *ngIf="username.errors.minLength">username must have at least 3 characters</div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">password</label>
                <input formControlName="password"
                 class="form-control" 
                id="password"
                type="text">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid">
                        <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">password is required !</div>
                </div>
        </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Enregistre</button>
</form>
```

**signup-form.component.ts**

```
 form = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3)
    ]),
    password: new FormControl('',Validators.required)
  })
  get username(){
    return this.form.get('username');
  }

  get password(){
    return this.form.get('password');
  }
```

Comment: this.form.controls.username

Comment: @AbdulAleem he give me error "this.form.controls.get is not a function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print whole error object and get to known what is properties inside `errors` object

```
 <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="username.touched && username.invalid">
    <div *ngIf="username.errors.required">username is required !</div>
    {{username.errors | json}}
    <div *ngIf="username.errors.minlength">username doit avoir au mois  cara !</div>
    <div *ngIf="username.errors.cannotContainSpace">username pas d'espace !</div>
 </div>
```

`L` should be small in `minlength`

Answer (score 0):

Add to your html:

```
<div *ngIf="form.get('username').hasError('minlength')">name must have at least 3 characters !</div>
```