# personnaliser la validation, message is not displayed

Tags: angular

I want to display the error message "the username should not have spaces", the red bar appears but without message.

**signup-form.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">username</label>
            <input formControlName="username"
             class="form-control" 
            id="username"
            type="text">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="username.touched && username.invalid">
                    <div *ngIf="username.errors.required">username is required !</div>
                    <div *ngIf="this.form.controls['username'].errors.minlength">username must have at least {{ username.errors.minlength.requiredLength }} characters</div>
                    <div *ngIf="username.errors.cannotContainSpace">username pas d'espace !</div>
                    {{username.errors | json}}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">password</label>
                <input formControlName="password"
                 class="form-control" 
                id="password"
                type="text">
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="password.touched && password.invalid">
                <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">password is required !</div>
                </div>
        </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Enregistre</button>
</form>
```

**signup-form.component.ts**

```
 form = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('',[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
      UsernameValidator.cannotContainSpace
    ]),
    password: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
  })
  get username(){
    return this.form.get('username');
  }

  get password(){
    return this.form.get('password');
  }
```

**username.validator.ts**

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from "@angular/forms";

export class UsernameValidator {
   static  cannotContainSpace(control:AbstractControl):ValidationErrors | null {
        if((control.value as string).indexOf(' ')>0)
         return {
            cannotContainSpace:false
         }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REACTIVE FORM SPECIFIC VALIDATION no message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57993937/reactive-form-specific-validation-no-message)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template you check if `cannotContainSpace` is true but you always set it to false.